# Rails 3.1 migrations drops timestamp in migration filenames

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-migrations

I am trying to upgrade an application from Rails 3.0.7 to 3.1.1. When I try to run a migration under 3.1.1, the migration file gets generated but without the leading timestamp. For example:

```
$ rails g migration add_foo_to_users foo:boolean
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/_add_foo_to_users.rb
```

The contents of the generated file look correct (with the new cool change method), but the migration file seems like it should be named more like db/migrate/20111012002448_add_foo_to_users.rb.

I suspect that I am missing something simple, but spent all weekend trying to figure out what it is. Search shows nothing helpful that I found. Migrations have been working all along before this, so something in the steps I took to upgrade seems to have broken it. Any suggestions of where to look would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you should add your update as an answer and accept it.
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have traced this issue down and fixed it in the GateGuru fork of also_migrate. A pull request is pending for merge back into also_migrate.

For anyone bitten by this in the interim, the pull request is at: https://github.com/winton/also_migrate/pull/10

You can also install from my fork via Bundler to fix the issue:

```
gem 'also_migrate', '0.3.5', :git => 'git@github.com:GateGuru/also_migrate.git', :branch => '8-fix-rails-3_1-timestamps'
```

Comment: I changed this to the accepted answer since it includes an actual fix. I need to get setup on Github in order to test this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone ends up here after hitting the same problem. After copying the entire application to another directory, and comparing to a clean install of a new Rails application, I narrowed this down to the configuration block for the also_migrate gem. When I comment out the lines for this configuration, the migration files were generated properly. Uncommenting the same lines recreates the error.